# Set interfaces in Java

Tags: java, generics, interface, set

What is the best way to implement a set interface in Java? Or more specifically, what is the best abstract data type to use when implementing a set interface? I need to create a set class in Java that implements a given set interface, but I'm wondering what the simplest way to do this is.

Comment: This is a bit off-topic ... this look like a request for documentation. Have you done some research ?

Answer (score 1):

An interface example is [java.util.Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), which is implemented by [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) and [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).